# CoreData and preload sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I am trying to preload sqlite for coredata. I tried tutorials like this and it is okay.

http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/

But, for some part, I am a bit unclear.

1) Is coredata layer is on top on sqlite? Or they have separate database?

2) What is the way of preloading sqlite? Is it like reading sqlite row 1 by 1 and save to core data? Or we ask core data to use sqlite file as base database?

```
 if managedObjectContext.save(&error) != true {} //From that example, it read csv file and save to core data..
```

3) If it is reading sqlite row 1 by 1, and if I have thousands of row, it will be slow. Can I just make core data point to my sqlite file?

**Modified**

If I wrote like this, does this mean I am pointing to my existing sqlite?

```
NSURL *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *storeURL = [applicationDocumentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
[self.persistentStoreCoordinator_busservice addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Core data is a framework that gives you easy way to store and retrieve data from the data store. Now the data store can be [SQLite, xml, binary files or in-memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html).

2) You can read and write one by one row (I won't recommend this) and the second one is to have the SQLite structure same as created by your core data and the copy your sqlite to the same place where you core data looks for the sqlite file.

3) Already answered, Yes you can place (copy) your sqlite file in same location (document directory) where your core data looks for sqlite file (defined in AppDelegate)

Comment: Thanks. I have added my code. Does this means that my core data is now pointing to my sqlite?